# Display selected form items in another page with Flask

Tags: python, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, flask

I'm using Flask 0.12 with Python 3.6 to create a simple app that will display selected items in another page when the submit button is clicked.

The main Flask app is in `app.py` as:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/result', methods=['POST'])
def result():
    return render_template('result.html')
```

This renders the following webpage using Bootstrap:

```
<h1>Example Page</h1>

<p>Choose the options in the form below then submit your selections.</p>

<form action="">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="vehicle">Vehicle</label>
    <select id="vehicle" class="form-control">
      <option>truck</option>
      <option>car</option>
      <option>van</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="year">Year</label>
    <select id="year" class="form-control">
      <option>1972</option>
      <option>1999</option>
      <option>2010</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>

<br>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

How can I get Flask to show the selected items in my `results.html` template when the submit button is clicked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make few changes in the form to display in result page.

1. You have to add action url and method in form

   ```
   <form action="/result" method="post">
   ```
2. Add name in the select field

   ```
   <select id="vehicle" class="form-control" name="vehicle">
   <select id="year" class="form-control" name="year">
   ```
3. Use flask request to get the form values

   ```
   from flask import request

   # inside your POST view
   vehicle = request.form.get('vehicle')
   year = request.form.get('year')
   return render_template('result.html', vehicle=vehicle, year=year)
   ```
4. Finally in your result html page add these...

   ```
   {{ vehicle }} {{ year }}
   ```

Comment: In step 4, should it be `{{ year }}` instead of `{{ result }}`?

Comment: fixed step 4 in your answer, this seems to work, thanks